# Conditions Imposed on a Ordering of Letters

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

---

Question:

> How many strings can be formed by ordering the letters $ABCDE$ if the string must contain the letters $ACE$ together in any order?

---

Attempt:

There are three positions for the $(ACE)$-cluster:
$$\overset{\text{Case 1}}{(ACE)\star\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 2}}{\star(ACE)\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 3}}{\star\star(ACE)}$$
Here, ``$\star$" can be either $B$ or $D$. For Case 1 we have the following:
$$(\underset{\_}{3}\underset{\_}{2}\underset{\_}{1})\underset{\_}{2}\underset{\_}{1}=3!\cdot 2!=12$$
For Case 2 we have the following:
$$\underset{\_}{2}(\underset{\_}{3}\underset{\_}{2}\underset{\_}{1})\underset{\_}{1}=2\cdot 3!\cdot 1=12$$
For Case 3 we have the following:
$$\underset{\_}{2}\underset{\_}{1}(\underset{\_}{3}\underset{\_}{2}\underset{\_}{1})=2!\cdot 3!=12$$
Thus, there are $36$ possible ways to order these five letters given the constraint.

---

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. You can also think of it this way: essentially you’re ordering three things, the $ACE$ cluster, the $B$, and the $D$, and you can do this in $3!=6$ ways. Once you’ve done this, you must order the $3$ letters in the cluster, something that you can also do in $3!=6$ ways. Thus, the entire task can be accomplished in $(3!)^2=36$ ways.